"To the extent that" means "if" or "when"?
Here's the explanation of to the extent of in Cambridge Dictionary:

to a particular degree or stage, often causing particular results

This meaning makes perfect sense in the following example sentence:

Sales have fallen badly this year, to the extent that we will have to close some of our stores.

However, it doesn't make as much sense in the following context (an article from NYT):

The second is that, to the extent polls have been wrong in recent presidential elections, they’ve been wrong because they’ve been biased toward Democrats.

As a result of my further research, I find two other sources that cover this topic:

A phrase increasingly used on cable news when the words "if" and "when" would be more concise without sacrificing accuracy. The reason why it's used this way is because it sounds less abrasive - Urban Dictionary
This meant that, in this instance, the words "to the extent that" could have been replaced by "if". (The question of what "to the extent that" means was recently considered by the High Court in Zayo Group v. Ainger - source)

My question is: Could "To the extent that" mean "if" or "when"?

I don't read 'if' or 'when.' I read "to the extent (that)" as "as far as you agree that": to the extent polls (as much as they) have been wrong ... , they’ve been ... biased toward Democrats.

It refers to the quantity of something, a large amount in the case of the fall in sales, a small amount in the case of polling errors.


My question is: Could "To the extent that" mean "if" or "when"?

This seems to be a possible gripe about the changing use of language. Language changes, otherwise none of us would need a translation of Beowulf.
Your sources are accurate "To the extent that" does not mean "if" or "when".
If I were a millionaire, I would buy a yacht.
When I am a millionaire, I will buy a yacht.
When[ever] I go to the marina, I buy a yacht.

To the extent that I am a millionaire, I will/would buy a yacht.

To the extent that I go to the marina, I buy a yacht.


But people seem to use it that way and it upsets some people. If it upsets enough people, then the speaker will lose their job. If it catches on, the speaker's name will be recorded in the OED as "the earliest record."
That said, to me, in your examples "to the extent that" seems to mean "limiting my arguments to"

It depends by what you mean by could … mean. You’ve cited evidence that some speakers do use it with that meaning. That’s what’s known as a descriptive account. But the passage you cite from Urban Dictionary reads more as prescriptive: not about how language is used, but about how it ought to be used.
In any event, the primary meaning of the phrase is illustrated by

To the extent that you practice piano, your performance will improve,

which means that the more one practices, the better one does, or by

To the extent that her lungs are damaged, she’ll have trouble with physical exertion,

which means that I don’t know how bad the state of her lungs is at present, but the severity of her condition can be expected to be reflected in the degree of difficulty she experiences while exercising.
